# Mikrotik - redirecting YouTube to a local friendly page

Tags: redirect, https, mikrotik, dnat, hsts

I'm configuring a rb750. I would like to drop YouTube access and redirect to a friendly page located in our local webserver. I can drop using l7 firewall but I'm not able to redirect user because https. Specifically you tube uses some kind of technology that blocks this "interceptation". I tried by dnat and DNS too but both didn't work :(.
I've read about hsts ( https strict transport security) that works on chrome, Firefox and others and allow full https during a site navigation and that's why I'm not able to do this. 
Have you guys some idea?

Comment: You can't - this is _exactly_ what SSL/TLS + HSTS is designed to bypass. It's possible that you could hijack the youtube.com DNS entry on your network though and point that to a server under your control - but you'd need to hijack all of the different variations and regional TLDs for YouTube

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for delay. I'm working a lot. I tried to do it via simple DNS. Just creating a static entrie and redirecting to a local server but it didn't work too. I can't understand when you say hijack and I'm afraid cause I have no time to learn it :(

Answer (score 6):

**If you don't have administrative rights on the client, you can't.**
(because it's considered as an attack)

If you have administrative rights on the clients, you can install there your own certificate authority, and use a certificate signed by that certificate authority to redirect users using https (So you will comply with HSTS, and HPKP/PKP is bypassed for locally imported root).

If it's a hotspot with a welcome page, you can explain on that page why some websites are blocked. (See https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/network-portal-detection )

Comment: I haven't because it is a public infrastructure. It is a hotspot and my clients can't access YouTube because our data plan is limited.

Comment: I've completed the answer with a link for captive portal: You can have a welcome page that explains why youtube is blocked. What you can do too is limit the bandwith of youtube instead of blocking it.